# How to update my location on activity when I am on other application

Tags: java, android

I have an app that the activity sends the user location to the server, how do I get the activity to keep sending the location to the server even when the application is in the background and the user is currently using another app?

For example 
I need that my application will work something like in WhatsApp "share my current location live" or Yango that even if the driver is on navigation and the app is in the background the user still gets the driver current location.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, create a Service which is going to be reading the location and doing that. It get's a bit more complicated because Android added restrictions to background services and the rate at which apps in the background can get updates on new device location. [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) explains about services. The service will be started from the activity. The service will contain the code for fetching the locations

Comment: I need that my application will work something like in WhatsApp "share my current location live" or Yango that even if WhatsApp is in the background the server still gets my location every few seconds.

Comment: This is possible, but for a limited amount of time based on android OS version on which the app is running. Where have you reached so far in implementing the background service which is requesting for the location?